# How can I prevent enlarging on text causing a line break on hover?

Tags: flexbox

I have positioned a list with text links using flexbox.

On hover I want to increase the text size of the hovered link and all other texts should move naturally.

As soon as a text is too big to fit in the original line, I have a problem.

The text will enlarge and jump to the next line - then loses the hover status and shrinks again - then hovering again and growing.

This causes the text to jump back and forth.

Does anyone have an idea how I can get this effect nice?
codepen.io/brilliant-coding/pen/xxyKeWG